# SQL - using the with clause, getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following sql statement in MSSQL 2008.

```
use gasnominations

INSERT INTO dbo.GasData (readDate,TagName,Value, amendedValue)

with emptce as
(SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
                SET starttime =''yesterday +6h'', endtime =''today +6h''  
                SELECT timestamp, tagname, value
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = "UMIS.99FC9051.F_CV"
                   OR tagname = "UMIS.99F851C.F_CV"
                   OR tagname = "UMIS.35GTGAS.F_CV"
                   OR tagname = "UMIS.35HRSGGAS.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99XXG546.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99XXG547.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99F9082.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FC20107.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.95FIQ5043.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99PBGAS.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FE1200.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FC8279.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.35FI8316.F_CV"
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
                AND SamplingMode =Calculated
                AND CalculationMode =Average
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp'))
                select emptce.Interval, emptce.TagName, emptce.Value, gasdata.amendedValue  from emptce inner join gasdata on emptce.TagName = gasData.tagName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
and emptce.Interval = DATEADD(DAY, 1, readDate)
```

I get the following error 'If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.'

I have tried adding a semi colon before the with but it just then errors on the ;

Comment: did you add the semi colon just before the With? So it became ;With?

Comment: You need to terminate *each* statement with a semicolon `;` (not prepend the `with` statement using a *termination* character). See here: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: 03Usr - yes and I also tried after the insert statement.  Still didnt work

Comment: The `WITH` goes on top of the `INSERT` statement, and the previous statement needs to be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
with emptce as
(SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) as TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 3), ROUND(value, 3)) As Value
FROM 
   OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
                SET starttime =''yesterday +6h'', endtime =''today +6h''  
                SELECT timestamp, tagname, value
                FROM ihRawData
                WHERE tagname = "UMIS.99FC9051.F_CV"
                   OR tagname = "UMIS.99F851C.F_CV"
                   OR tagname = "UMIS.35GTGAS.F_CV"
                   OR tagname = "UMIS.35HRSGGAS.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99XXG546.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99XXG547.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99F9082.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FC20107.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.95FIQ5043.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99PBGAS.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FE1100.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FE1200.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.99FC8279.F_CV"
       OR tagname = "UMIS.35FI8316.F_CV"
                AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
                AND SamplingMode =Calculated
                AND CalculationMode =Average
                AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
                ORDER BY tagname, timestamp'))
                INSERT INTO dbo.GasData (readDate,TagName,Value, amendedValue)
                select emptce.Interval, emptce.TagName, emptce.Value, gasdata.amendedValue                  
                from emptce inner join gasdata on emptce.TagName = gasData.tagName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
and emptce.Interval = DATEADD(DAY, 1, readDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminate the previous statement with a semicolon, and then use `WITH` in advance of `INSERT`.

```
use gasnominations;

with emptce as (...)
INSERT INTO dbo.GasData (readDate,TagName,Value, amendedValue)
select emptce.Interval, emptce.TagName, emptce.Value, gasdata.amendedValue  from emptce inner join gasdata on emptce.TagName = gasData.tagName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
and emptce.Interval = DATEADD(DAY, 1, readDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find the USE statement needs to be followed by a GO when using multiple statements

```
use gasnominations
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.GasData (readDate,TagName,Value, amendedValue);

WITH ....
```

Comment: thanks but I still get Incorrect syntax near ';' after amendvalue)